# Text Editors with the smallest total LOC

Tags: software-rec, editors, source-code

I'm aware of certain Text Editors that would be called "small" in term of LOC, or "Line Of Code". I'm also aware it's no the best way to demonstrate (nor the only one) how small a codebase is, but it is the one I decided to use for this post.

A couple of existing Editors that would relate to this are:

- [bte](https://github.com/Sidd-Dino/bte) or "Bash Text Editor" (made in bash), 1201 LOC.
- [kilo](https://github.com/antirez/kilo), made in C, 1308 LOC.

There probably others, but i do not know of any other alternative (in the same spirit as what was already mentioned above, with similar or smaller total LOC). I'm mainly interested in those kind of project so that i can study their respective internal logic and codebase.

Any other recommendation similar to this (even in other programming languages) is welcome.

Comment: What should your text editor be able to do? For example `read -e` in `bash` is a single-line text editor

Comment: basically, whatever text editor usually do...but in the smallest total LOC. Basic things like *editing* (obviously, it does come from the previous statement "Text Editor"), deleting text, adding text, saving text... @roaima

Comment: [One implementation](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring01/cs333/ed.c) of `ed` has 1700

Comment: "Whatever text editors usually do"? My `emacs` does text manipulation, reads News, manipulates directories, supports `emacs` packages, and provides a complete Lisp programming environment. Is that what you mean by "whatever text editors usually do"?

Comment: Why is LOC an interesting measurement? Unless you have to retype the source, who cares how long it is?

Comment: I mean...I did said it was to study it's "internal logic and codebase", which *imply* that it would help doing so, if the codebase was small enough for me to do that (eg: small LOC). And I also did mention what you said when saying that this isn't the only way to mention the size of a codebase :) @waltinator

Comment: I'm aware of `ed` and it's forks...I didn't include it in my post because I'm somewhat unsure i would think of it as a text editor (given it's technically a line editor, not the same thing, but work similarly), *and* also because most `ed` clone/fork always are the same, as they always have the same exact features, compared to existing "text editors", which always varies quite a bit (beside the basic part of editing i mentioned in my previous comment to you) @roaima

Comment: I already mentioned in my post and to another comment that, it has to be small as a codebase (thus LOC is used here to illustrate that easier). The reason? Already stated too :) (so that it can be studied better). @waltinator

Comment: I never *only* said "whatever text editors usually do"...I explicitly said "whatever text editors usually do" *in* the context of a "small codebase/LOC"...sorry if you took it out of context. @waltinator

Comment: please reconsider voting to close this, as this isn't "opinion based", and it is technically based on a specific logic/metric, being `LOC`, and the goal being studying those smaller codebase...@AdminBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kibi](https://github.com/ilai-deutel/kibi/tree/master/src), made in Rust. This project is [inspired](https://github.com/ilai-deutel/kibi#comparison-with-kilo) by kilo.

<del>If you fine with js,</del> [pell](https://github.com/jaredreich/pell) is also pretty interesting.

Bonus: [World Smallest Text Editor](https://github.com/philiparvidsson/Worlds-Smallest-Text-Editor/blob/master/src/main.asm) (Sorry it's win32, that's why it's bonus)

<del>Bonus2: [Suit Yourself](https://github.com/topics/text-editor)</del>